# Is it possible to efficiently search a bit-trie for values less than the key?

Tags: search, data-structures, trie

I am currently storing a large number of unsigned 32-bit integers in a [bit trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Bitwise_tries) (effectively forming a binary tree with a node for each bit in the 32-bit value.)  This is very efficient for fast lookup of exact values.

I now want to be able to search for keys that may or may not be in the trie and find the value for the first key less than or equal to the search key.  **Is this efficiently possible with a bit trie, or should I use a different data structure?**

I am using a trie due to its speed and cache locality, and ideally want to sacrifice neither.

---

For example, suppose the trie has two keys added:

- `0x00AABBCC`
- `0x00AABB00`

and I an now searching for a key that is not present, `0x00AABB11`.  I would like to find the first key present in the tree with a value <= the search key, which in this case would be the node for `0x00AABB00`.

While I've thought of a possible algorithm for this, I am seeking concrete information on if it is *efficiently* possible and/or if there are *known algorithms* for this, which will no doubt be better than my own.

Comment: Seems like the general case would involve some amount of backtracking. In the worst case, that backtracking could be very expensive, no?

Comment: @JimMischel That's what I'm worried about. Is there a better data structure with similar properties (searchable for <=, good cache locality, fast?)

Answer (score 1):

We can think bit trie as a binary search tree.  In fact, it is a binary search tree. Take the 32-bit trie for example, suppose left child as 0, right child as 1. For the root, the left subtree is for the numbers less than 0x80000000 and the right subtree is for the numbers no less than 0x80000000, so on and so forth. So you can just use the similar the method to find the largest item not larger than the search key in the binary search tree. Just don't worry about the backtracks, it won't backtrack too much and won't change the search complexity. 
When you match fails in the bit trie, just backtrack to find the right-most child of the nearest ancestor of the failed node.

Comment: The 32-bit bit trie requires that 32 nodes be visited in order to determine if a particular value exists. If the trie contained two items, 0x80000001 and 0x7ffffffff, and was queried to find the first value <= 0x800000000, it would have to follow the right path all the way down to 0x80000001, backtrack to the root, and follow the left path down to 0x7fffffff. So, yes, it's the same complexity O(n), where n is the number of bits. Worst case requires 3 times as long. Granted, average case backtracking will likely be only a few extra nodes.

Comment: @JimMischel yeah, I think it will be efficient enough. To compare two 32-bit integers, the worst case needs to compare all 32-bits..To make bit trie more efficient, maybe we can implement with 4-fork tree or 16-fork tree, but binary tree.

Comment: Ok - this is pretty much what I was thinking, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the data is static--you're not adding or removing items--then I'd take a good look at using a simple array with binary search. You sacrifice cache locality, but that might not be catastrophic. I don't see cache locality as an end in itself, but rather a means of making the data structure fast.

You might get better cache locality by creating a balanced binary tree in an array. Position 0 is the root node, position 1 is left node, position 2 is right node, etc. It's the same structure you'd use for a binary heap. If you're willing to allocate another 4 bytes per node, you could make it a left-threaded binary tree so that if you search for X and end up at the next larger value, following that left thread would give you the next smaller value. All told, though, I don't see where this can outperform the plain array in the general case.

A lot depends on how sparse your data is and what the range is. If you're looking at a few thousand possible values in the range 0 to 4 billion, then the binary search looks pretty attractive. If you're talking about 500 million distinct values, then I'd look at allocating a bit array (500 megabytes) and doing a direct lookup with linear backward scan. That would give you very good cache locality.

Comment: Thanks Jim! It's not static, but it is read from a lot more than it is written to. I don't have a good handle on data quantity yet, but I'd say a million or more entries. Entries will be spaced apart by anything from 16 to a million or two.  Could you expand on the bit array idea, please? (One bit per, say, 16-spaced increment?) (Although 250MB sounds like far, far too much.)

Comment: @DavidM: The bit array idea assumed allocating an array of 4 billion (2^32) bits (the range of a 32 bit integer). If you had a whole lot of numbers, then the average distance between them would be relatively small and a probe plus sequential scan would be very fast. With only a few millions (or tens of millions) of items, number spacing would be too large and the sequential scan would probably be too expensive. And I made a mistake. That bit array would require 500 MB, not 250 MB.

Answer (score 1):

A bit trie walks 32 nodes in the best case when the item is found.

A million entries in a red-black tree like `std::map` or java.util.TreeMap would only require log2(1,000,000) or roughly 20 nodes per query, worst case.  And you do not always need to go to the bottom of the tree making average case appealing.

When backtracking to find `<=` the difference is even more pronounced.

The fewer entries you have, the better the case for a red-black tree

At a minimum, I would compare any solution to a red-black tree.